# Conditionally Change Debounce Execution Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where a user enters their address. My JavaScript will save the form once the user has finished entering their information without the need for clicking a submit button.

The problem I am having is with the `debounce` function. For basic text input fields, I want the `debounce` to apply its wait time. For my final field that is simply a checkbox for marking the shipping address the same as billing, I want this to fire a form submit on click if it's checked. I'm able to accomplish this task, but I'm having a problem with my listeners overlapping each each other since the debounce for my text fields have a different timeout than my `submit-now` listener for my same as billing checkbox which simply submits my form immediately.

I have two different classes assigned to my inputs. The first is `submit-now` and the second is `submit-later`, with `submit-now` firing immediately and `submit-later` firing after 1700 milliseconds of no activity.

Here is my debounce function:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    }
}
```

Listener #1:

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '.submit-later', debounce(function(e){
    submitForm();
}, 1700));
```

The keyup listener is for user input and the change listener is for autofill.

Listener #2 (problem listener):

```
//Notice this function does not call debounce.
//Even if it did, I would have to create a new instance of debouce with 0 ms but this would defeat the purpose since it would be using a different instance of debounce. 
$(document).on('change', '.submit-now', function(e){
    submitForm();
});
```

Ultimately, it would be great if I could make both listeners use the same instance of `debounce` but `debounce` needs a way to know whether or not it should continue to wait for user input or submit my form based on the fired listener.

Comment: Why don't you write a function like $(document).on('submit', function(){ // do function 1, then fire function 2 after function 1 is done instead of a timeout

Comment: @Keith I don't entirely understand what you're suggesting. Both listeners should be firing the same form but they should only fire it once rather than twice due to the debounce function.

Comment: You have the submitForm function being called in 2 different functions. Why not only submitForm once and do a callback in the second function where you run the first and then the second after the first one is completed

Comment: @Keith Wouldn't that result in my `submit-now` listener having to trigger the `submit-later` listener? Have I misunderstood?

Comment: You said, The first is submit-now and the second is submit-later, with submit-now firing immediately and submit-later firing after 1700 milliseconds of no activity., so does submit-later not fire after submit-now?

Comment: It does in some (most) cases. For example, the form won't submit if it's not completely filled out (has required fields). But if a user comes back and changes their zip code for example (submit-later) and then immediately clicks same as billing checkbox (submit-now) the form will submit, then submit again after the debounce from the original submit-later expires. @Keith

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but you can wrap everything in one function.

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(event){   
   if(valdiationCheck()){
       $('#form').submit();
   }
});

function validationCheck(){
   // run validations
}
```

You are doing the validation check on any change and if everything checks out you submit the form.